# Subtract in set intervals across 2 values in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I am trying to write a PTO calculator in Excel and need help subtracting paid time off.  The part I can't get to work is it subtracts in quarter-hour increments, but instead of using an HH:MM format, the times are scaled to 100.

Example:

```
    |     A        |  B    
  --|--------------|--------
   1| Bank         |50.00
   2| CY           | 6.40
    |--------------|--------
   3| Used         | 9.50
    |--------------|--------
   4| Bank Remain  |
   5| CY Remain    |
```

The `Used` would subtract from `CY Accrued` first until it is less than `0.25`, then it will subtract the rest from `Bank Accrued`.

Thanks for the help.  I did look for similar questions, but the only ones I saw calculated time in standard format (15 min intervals) not time proportioned to a 100 scale.

Comment: Would help if you show us an example of how you have structured your data

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, I inserted a table similar to the answer below, but vertical, which is how it looks in my Excel sheet.  This way, it visually resembles a standard subtraction problem to see what I am trying to accomplish.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this should go in it's own answer or not, since the principle is the same as the answer from @ReyJuna, but the execution is somewhat different.  Using the table from the question:

```
    |     A        |  B    
  --|--------------|--------
   1| Bank         |50.00
   2| CY           | 6.40
    |--------------|--------
   3| Used         | 9.50
    |--------------|--------
   4| Bank Remain  |46.75
   5| CY Remain    | 0.15
```

Starting with finding `CY Remain`, if `CY` is greater than `Used` you don't have to worry about running out of `0.25` increment segments, so you can directly subtract using `B2-B3` in the function below.

When `CY` is less than `Used`, you only want groups of exactly `0.25`, so you can use the `TRUNC()` function to drop the decimals.  The function is:

`=IF(B2<B3,B2-(TRUNC(B2/0.25)*0.25),B2-B3)`

Since you want to stop subtracting at `CY` less than `0.25`, all you have to do is get the number of `0.25` groups in `CY` and subtract that.  The rest that needs to be subtracted from `Bank` will be handled by this function:

`=IF(B2<B3,B1-(B3-TRUNC(B2/0.25)*0.25),B1)`

Notice the `TRUNC(B2/0.25)*0.25` is the same, but is now subtracted from the value in `Used`.  This gives you what is left over after the correct amount has been subtracted from `CY` first.  Finally, when the `Bank Remain` function is false, meaning Bank PTO is not needed, then `B1` is returned as it went unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes using a formula instead of VBA and I have laid out the data in a simple table (see below) where the CY Old Balance is in cell `B2`.

```
| |     A       |  B   |   C   |    D     |
| |-------------|------|-------|----------|
|1|             | CY   | BANK  | PTO Used |
|2| Old Balance | 6.4  | 50    | 9.5      |
|3| New Balance | 0.15 | 46.75 |          |
```

The formula for the CY New Balance cell (`B3`) is:

```
=IF(B2>=D2,B2-D2,B2-0.25*INT(B2/0.25))
```

If the CY Old Balance is greater than or equal to the PTO Used, then I have assumed that the entire used amount is subtracted.

The `B2-0.25*INT(B2/0.25)` portion calculates how many whole portions of `.25` are in your Old Balance and then subtracts that from your Old Balance giving you the CY New Balance.

The formula for the BANK New Balance cell (`C3`) is similar:

```
=IF(B2>=D2,C2,C2-(D2-0.25*INT(B2/0.25)))
```

The first part of the `IF` is based on the same assumption as above.

The `C2-(D2-0.25*INT(B2/0.25))` uses the same "whole portions of `.25`" approach, then subtracts that from PTO Used to get what remains.  That is then subtracted from BANK Old Balance to get the New Balance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I actually figured it out after I walked away and stopped thinking about it for the night.  Your solution is close to mine, with minor differences like `TRUNC()` instead of `INT()`.  However, I think in your equation for BANK New Balance, the _value if true_ statement should not be zero.  This would return `0` and would make it look like the person lost all their BANK PTO if indeed `B2>=D2`.  In reality, they would have all of it so the function should probably be: `=IF(B2>=D2,C2,C2-(D2-0.25*INT(B2/0.25)))`

Comment: You are correct.  I have corrected the formula for the BANK New Balance cell (C3).  However, I didn't change the table format since you provided an answer for that configuration.